# Searching a dictionary for a key, adding the value of that key's value to another key value pair

Tags: python, dictionary

Ok, so I've got, say, a dictionary, with a lot of key: value pairs:

```
   worddict = {'example1': 1, 'example2': 0, 'example3': 7}
```

I want to go over certain keys, and get their values, and add it to another key: value pair's value. For example:

pseudocode:

```
seconddict = {'firstitem': 1, 'seconditem': 1, 'thirditem':9}

for x in worddict:
    if x.key = example1:
        seconddict{'firstitem'.value} + example1.value
```

I think I have the right general idea, but not the syntax.

But basically, firstitem's value would increase by the exact same number as the value of example1

Basically, I've got a list of words, and these words are in certain categories. Any word in any of those category is going to tick the value up of that category by one.

EDIT:

Expected output is if a key from the first dictionary has a value, that value will be added to a specific key's value from the second dictionary.

So in this case, firstitem's value would become "2", because it was 1 to start with, and example1 is in the "firstname" category.

Comment: Dicts don't have a well-defined order. What do you mean by "firstitem"? Do you want anything to happen to "seconditem" and "thirditem"?

Comment: what's your expected output here?

Comment: You need to read the Python tutorial to learn how to use dicts.

Comment: `you've a list of words and these words are in certain categories`, may be you're doing it in wrong way.

Comment: How do we know that 'example1 is in the "firstname" category' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** The comment of the OP makes it clear that words can be in more than one category. Code adjusted.

---

I think you want to **accumulate** the values of the words **by category**. One (simple) way to do it would be:

```
def accumulate_by_category(word_values, cat_sums, cats):
    """ modify the category sums by adding the values of the given words """
    for word, value in word_values.items():
        for cat in cats[word]:
            cat_sums[cat] += value
```

You can use it like this:

```
worddict = {'example1': 1, 'example2': 0, 'example3': 7}
seconddict = {'firstitem': 1, 'seconditem': 1, 'thirditem':9}

categories = {'example1': ['firstitem', 'thirditem'],
              'example2': ['seconditem', 'thirditem'],
              'example3': ['thirditem']}

accumulate_by_category(worddict, seconddict, categories)
print(seconddict) # {'seconditem': 1, 'firstitem': 2, 'thirditem': 17}
```

Comment: Hrm, this works, except that if a word is in two categories, it can't add a value to both.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander: In that case, you need a mapping word --> list of categories. See updated answer.

Comment: Oh, that's all it needs, is to put a list as the value? Well that's a simple fix!

Comment: How do I make it so that ideas like this become more intuitive to me? I've read all the tutorial materials and used the language for quite a while, but complex data manipulation is still difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
for word,category in worddict.items():
    categoryCounts[category] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you're looking for something like this - if not, please post what your expected output is

```
my_list = [False, False, False, True, True, True]

worddict = {'example1': 1, 'example2': 0, 'example3': 7}
seconddict = {'firstitem': 1, 'seconditem': 1, 'thirditem':9}

keys_to_add = ['example1', 'example3']

for k in keys_to_add:
    seconddict['firstitem'] += worddict[k]

print seconddict
```

Answer (score -1):

```
seconddict = {}
for k,v in worddict.items():
 seconddict[v] = seconddict.get(v,0) + 1
```

Comment: This isn't very helpful to anyone but the person who asked the question.